# Eye Of Gnome (eog) keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, eog

Does there exists some list of keyboard shortcuts? I want to know how to turn photos (and other manipulations). I couldn't google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some but unfortuanley not all of the keyboard shortcuts are listed in the [GNOME Image Viewer Manual](http://library.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/index.html.en) that you will also get by pressing the "Help" button in Eye Of Gnome.

Keyboard shortcuts that are not listed may appear in the menu dropdown list (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for rotating clockwise or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for rotating counter clockwise).

Answer (score 2):

Rotate Clockwise: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Rotate Anti-clockwise: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

---

Unfortunately eog has no other 'photo editing' keyboard shortcuts as such. The easiest way to find out more shortcuts is to look in the menus and take note of the shortcuts listed next to the menu options.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the program help?  All the keyboard shortcuts are there (not in a nice table, but they are described) under "Getting Started" and "Viewing Images".

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I only read "man eog" and it was not inside.